# How do I make a Winforms program launch a regular class's method rather than launching a Form? Then I would like to launch a form if I want

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

How do I make a Winforms program launch a regular class's method rather than launching a Form? Then I would like to launch a form if I want

For example,

Normally when a winforms program launches, it shows Form1. That's the default. And it autmatically runs Form1's load method.

I can go to program.cs and change the `Application.Run(new Form1());` line to some other form..

But that's not what I want.

I want the benefit of having the forms..

But I don't want to be forced to start showing a form or to be forced to start with code within a form. So I don't want the entry code to be a form's load method. I want the entry to be some method within one of my own classes that I write from scratch, a class(a class that's not a form).

Comment: What would be the logic that decides if you show the form, or the other class? Do you have code to show us?

Comment: I am not sure if I follow what you are asking. _”I want the entry to be some method within one of my own classes that I write from scratch, a class(a class that's not a form).”_ ?  Is there some reason you cannot create your class “before” calling the `Application.Run(new Form1());` ?

Comment: @David.Warwick  The class would be like `class Abc {  public static void blah(){}  }`  it's not "shown".  I'd want something like `Abc.blah()` in program.cs to run it. And i'd want to always run it, so no conditional.

Comment: If you want the entry point to be a forms load method, that means that the form has loaded. So are you saying that you want to decide to load some other form, or some class after a form has been loaded? If that is what you want, then put the logic for what you want to load next in the load method.

Comment: @David.Warwick i'm saying I don't want the entry point to be a form's load method!

Comment: @JohnG i'll add some code to address your question.

Comment: Sorry @barlop, I misread your question. The entry point is never a form load method.

Comment: @David.Warwick I mean I want the entry to be program.cs as it is and then that to launch a method of a class, and I don't want a form load method to run automatically.

Comment: @JohnG I just tried something based on your suggestion and I think it worked.. i'll add some more detail..

Comment: @barlop,if you will never run the form, then remove Application.Run.

Comment: And do something else instead of Application.Run...

Comment: @JohnG I think this works and it was inspired by your question to me.   https://pastebin.com/raw/HE9EK1vh    you can post that as an answer. Thanks

Comment: Inside of static void Main, create a new object from your other class and call it's method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are asking? Team is a Class and its location determines which form to run.

```
static class Program {
  [STAThread]
  static void Main() {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Team team = new Team();
    if (team.TeamLocation == "Arizona") {
      Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    else {
      Application.Run(new Form2());
    }
  }
}
```

Again, I am not sure what exactly you are asking?

Comment: thanks, yeah I think I also hadn't realised that one has to start forms with that Application.Run line (I think in the past i've done `Form1 frm = new Form1(); 
 frm.show(); `

Comment: looking at the question you asked me I tried https://pastebin.com/raw/HE9EK1vh  and that worked.

Comment: @barlop ... the code in the pastebin looks a little awkward and a round about way to start specific forms, but it should work.

Comment: So do I need to move my home to run it in console mode? ;)

Comment: @barlop that example you posted has the net effect of a typical WinForms app anyway.  Not sure what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @MickyD it decouples things more, and gives me more control over where I can put  my code. And doesn't force me to start a form if I decide not to.

Comment: @barlop Perhaps.  BTW I think you mean _encapsulates_ not _"decouples"_.  [Static code analysis](https://www.ndepend.com/) will still show a direct dependency if `Class1` is in the same assembly as `Program`.

Comment: @MickyD  When I say decouples it,  I mean from a design perspective it decouples it.  (so if on a low level, code in class1.cs  is somehow tied to code in program.cs, by being in the same assembly, then that's another matter).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to open a form, you can just run another method. Note that a WinForms application will exit when your method is complete

```
static void Main()
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Show Form?", "Form", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    else
        SomeMethod();
}

static void SomeMethod()
{
    MessageBox.Show("No Form");
}
```

Note that you can also create a console application and add a form.

Comment: Thanks,  and that's really interesting, I didn't know you can create a console application and add a form..  Is there such a thing as a blank application, and you can launch a form or a console?

Comment: _"you can also create a console application and add a form"_ - its safer to make a WinForms app run in console mode than it is to make a Console App display a form due to default threading modes

Answer (score 0):

You need Bootstrapper to guide your start load form.

Here is an example in the below.

```
public class Bootstrapper 
{
    // Write you custom property or field, Here is an example
    private readonly Customfield _customfield = new Customfield();
    
    public Bootstrapper() 
    {
        // Configure your service
        ConfigureServices();
    }

    private void ConfigureServices()
    {
        // Added your service, catch exception or someting
        Application.ThreadException = (o, e) => { /* catch some exception. */}
    }
 
    // this is method entry point.
    public void Run() 
    {
        // You can change your Form1/Form2 before running.
        if (_customfield.Default) Application.Run(new Form1());
        else Application.Run(new Form2());
    }    
}

static void Main()
{
       Application.EnableVisualStyles();
       Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
       
       // Replace Application.Run(new Form1()) to bootstrapper.Run()
       var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
       bootstrapper.Run();
}
```